# 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. Error occurs while accessing xml file with "Windows Authentication" is enabled

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET website developed in .NET 4.5.2. The application works perfectly on all client machines except only one. The scenario is as below:

1. The website has an XML file `connectivity_check.xml`.
2. In IIS only the XML file is set with `Windows Authentication` enabled whereas all other options are disabled.
3. I have a `default.htm` page which has only JavaScript code. The code uses `XMLHttpRequest` or `ActiveXObject` conditionally. Both methods tries to load "connectivity_check.xml".
4. When default.htm tries to load an XML file using one of the methods above it throws a `401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.` error.

Using the Fiddler I reviewed the headers and found they `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate` and
`WWW-Authenticate: NTLM` as expected for windows authentication. Then why I'm getting invalid credentials error in this case? What could be the possible reasons for this error? Is there a way that I can check which invalid credentials are passed?

Comment: How about permissions on the server's file system? Is this file set to allow everyone for read (or at least for IUSR, or domain users or something)?

Comment: Yes, the IUSR, IIS_USR, and application pool users are set and allowed to read. I did try with everyone as well but I got the same error.

Comment: If you use your web browser to open the xml file (via the intended url), does it work, or prompt you? If it works and you navigate back to your default.htm, does it work now?

Comment: When access the XML file directly in browser it just prompts browser's pop-up window for windows authentication.

Comment: This is not a question any developer can easily answer. Involve your domain administrators so that they can investigate further on this 401 error. For example, Kerberos (in Negotiate) requires accurate time sync, so out of sync machines won't pass authentication.

Comment: If it works for everyone, but not for one person, I would check if that machine is on the domain or if that user has authenticated to the domain. Because the problem you are describing sounds more like the user has not authenticated and it is not happening automatically for this one user.

Comment: Is there any way that we could extract the user information from the request header? Because it points to "invalid credentials" in the error.

Comment: The main reason for the 401 – Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials error is that you are using a custom username as the application pool identity. If you enable the detailed errors, you will see an error page with many details and a sub-status code of 401, It will guide you to check the access control permissions of the file system.

Comment: @YurongDai, I am using my own application pool for the website. I have used the default AppPool but have the same result. Please guide me how I can get the sub-status code error?

Comment: When the server encounters an error, by default, the local server request returns a detailed error page, and the client returns a custom error page. You can change the setting to return a detailed error page. Open IIS, select your site and double click the Error Pages module, click Edit Feature Settings... then choose Detailed errors and save the setting. However, it is recommended that you set the client to return a custom error page to protect private information after checking the error message.

Answer (score 0):

A 401 response is the normal first step with Windows Authentication. At that point one of three things will happen:

1. The browser will prompt the user for credentials.
2. The browser will automatically send the credentials of the currently-logged-in user.
3. The browser will do nothing and the 401 will be the final result.

Because the file is being loaded by JavaScript, the browser will never prompt for credentials.

The browser will automatically send credentials only if the website is trusted. For Chrome and IE/Edge, that is done by adding the website to the Trusted Sites in Internet Options. Firefox [has it own setting](https://superuser.com/a/664673/233663).

It could also be the case that the credentials are being sent but are rejected. However, you would see this in Fiddler. It would look like this:

1. GET connectivity_check.xml
2. HTTP 401 response with WWW-Authenticate header
3. Another GET connectivity_check.xml with credentials included
4. Another HTTP 401 response

If you are only seeing one GET and one 401, then the browser just isn't automatically sending the credentials.

The quickest way to test what the problem is is to put the full URL to connectivity_check.xml into the browser's address bar and see what happens. If it prompts for credentials, type in the username/password manually. If it works, then you know that Windows Authentication works for that user and it's just a problem of not automatically sending credentials. In that case, check the Trusted Sites on that computer and add the website.